# Searchkick : GrandParent has_many Parent - Parent has_many Child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm working on search in a Ruby on Rails application using searchkick gem.

I have, say, three models `GrandParent` , `Parent` , and `Child` where:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :childs
```

and

```
class GrandParent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :parents
```

Say, `Parent` has a value `name`. And `Child` has a value `content`

When I try to find records in `GrandParent` which have `parents` with `name` that matches the search query I can use the following:

```
searchkick

def search_data
    {
        parents: parents.map(&:name).join(' '),
    }
end
```

But, how can I perform search to find records in `GrandParent` which have `parents` having `childs` with `content` value matching the search query?

In other words, if the query matches the content of a `Child` , It's `GrandParent` should be returned in the search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it done by adding the following to `GrandParent` model:

```
searchkick

def search_data
    {
        parents: parents.map(&:name).join(' '),
        childs: get_childs_contents.join(' ')
    }
end

def get_childs_contents
    a = []
    parents.each do |p|
        p.childs.each do |c|
            a << c.content
        end
    end
    return a
end
```